# Retrieve claims from a jwt with apex

Tags: apex, oauth2, jwt, crypto

I'm trying to retrieve the claims, audience, issuer, subject from a JWT in apex, according to this documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm

However it doesn't work obviously.

I receive a JWT as a string from the front end, I verify it with crypto.verify, and then I want to retrieve at least the audience, issuer, and subject.

When trying this

```
String aud = jwt.getAud();
```

I receive this error

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getAud() from the type String
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the payload, then deserialize it:

```
String[] parts = jwt.split('\\.');
Blob payloadDecoding = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(parts[1]); 
Map<String, Object> tokens = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payloadDecoding.toString());
String audience = (String)tokens.get('aud');
```

JWTs have three parts, separated by `.`, the header, payload, and signature. You can decode the first and second parts directly into JSON, while the third is encoded binary data for use to verify a token's authenticity.

Comment: thanks for the solutionn!